# How to read and delete a document in firestore collection as one operation in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, locking

I have a firestore collection and I would like to read and delete a document as one operation in kotlin. I want to make sure no other user is able to read the same document before I delete it.
Here is my code in kotlin. CollRef is reference to the firestore collection. MY Collection contains simple documents with fields only.
I found online to use lock mechanism or firebase security rule but I don't know how to implement them.

```
 private val db: FirebaseFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    private val collRef: CollectionReference = db.collection("Queue")
    runBlocking {
                val querySnapshot = collRef.limit(1).get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
                        if (!querySnapshot.isEmpty) {
                            val documentSnapshot = querySnapshot.documents[0]
                            if (documentSnapshot.data?.isNotEmpty()!!) {
                                db.runTransaction { transaction ->
                                    val snapshot = transaction.get(documentSnapshot.reference)
                                    if (snapshot.data?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
                                        transaction.delete(documentSnapshot.reference)
                                    }
                                    // Success
                                    null
                                }.addOnSuccessListener {
                                    Utils.data["from"] = documentSnapshot.data!!["from"]
                                    Utils.data["to"] = documentSnapshot.data!!["to"]
                                    Utils.data["sender"] = documentSnapshot.data!!["sender"]
                                    Utils.data["time"] = documentSnapshot.data!!["time"]
                                  
                                }
                                    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
    
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added my code. I am reading a random document from the collRef and onSuccess I want to delete the document. I am facing racing condition as  one can read the document before I delete it which is not what I need.